# Elixir/Phoenix: Missing beam file elf_format <<"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/hipe-3.11.2/ebin/elf_format.beam"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

While trying to compile a release of my Phoenix project, the following error comes up:

```
$ mix release
....
==> Generated .appup for myapp 0.0.1 -> 0.0.2
===> Missing beam file elf_format <<"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/hipe-3.11.2/ebin/elf_format.beam">>
could not find app plug {0,10,0}

$ elixir --version
Elixir 1.0.3
```

The Phoenix version is 0.10.0. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Phoenix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine. It is because you don't have hipe compiler enabled but you don't need one. Everything should work just fine™.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, it's about missing erlang-base-hipe package in ubuntu in my case.

See the issue that I have created regarding the same warning you get
https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/107

The solution here is
1. Just ignore. There is no harm in the warning. Though I believe exrm can produce better messages to the users and not confuse them.
2. Install erlang-base-hipe package which will resolve the issue.

If you go to https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp
and see the ubuntu tab, you will find this info as the last FAQ.

> 6. I have heard about HiPE. What is it? How to get it?
>
> HiPE stands for High-Performance Erlang Project. It is a native code
>   compiler for Erlang. In most cases, it positively affects performance.
>   If you want to download it, call the following:
>
> sudo apt-get install erlang-base-hipe This will replace the Erlang/OTP
>   runtime with a HiPE supported version. Other Erlang applications do
>   not need to be reinstalled. To return to the standard runtime, call:
>
> sudo apt-get install erlang-base